# I am trying to get data from Mango Automation into Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I work at an energy company and we are wanting to try introduce Power BI into our business after countless recommendations. Currently we are using this tool called Mango, it does offer dashboarding, but the tools it provides are very limited and have low amounts of customization available.

I am currently trying to get data from Mango into PowerBI but am having no luck. I understand Mango probably isn't that well known, so here is a bit about it that may prove helpful.

"Mango collects its data by reading from its various data sources every so often. This period varies depending on how critical the data from each data source is deemed. PLC’s controlling generators are normally every 30 seconds or sooner, but other devices might only be read every 5 or 10 minutes. The data that Mango collects is stored in its database based on specific settings customised for each data source and even further customised for each data point within each data source.

Mango SCADA units are primarily designed to go and get data from other devices rather than send data out to other devices, and as such they support a lot of different protocols over ethernet and serial interfaces to get that data, including the main one we use Modbus IP."

They do have a very limited “Publisher” feature that can send their data to other devices. The types supported are Modbus, BACnet, and HTTP Sender.

I don't want this to come across as if I haven't tried to research about this, my main role is just not technologically focused, so a lot of the terminology is foreign to me. I would appreciate any help offered, even if this is just pointing me in the right direction. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

A description of the API can be found here:
I am not clear on whether you have access to the API directly or if you need to access the data in another way.
https://docs-v3.mango-os.com/explore-the-api

Then in PowerBi you use "get data" and choose WEB
This will generate something like

Json.Document(Web.Contents("[Your API URL]"))